# Rails:How to create a time column with timezone on postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timezone, utc

I have a **rails** application which works on **postgres** db. I have a model called UserTimings where there are two fields from_time and to_time.

```
t.time     "from_time"
t.time     "to_time"
```

I expected that the time will be stored in complete UTC format with timezone information. After a little while, I realized that the database has this kind SQL query to create the table.

```
from_time time without time zone,
to_time time without time zone,
```

I do not want this. I want to store with **time zone**. I want the +0530 thingy in the UTC time which I'm not getting althought the rails application has been configured to handle it. Please tell me how to write a migration to force the db to use the time zone.

Thank you.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-in-rails-2-1 This railscast says that we have to have a time_zone:string column in our record. But Postgres already has the support for time zone! How can I avail that feature?

Comment: I want both time and timezone. How to specify in rails migration specifically for postgres to create a column for time along with time zone?

Answer (score 25):

That migration do exactly what you want

```
class CreatePeppers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :peppers do |t|
      t.column :runs, 'timestamp with time zone'
      t.column :stops, 'time with time zone'
    end
  end
end
```

Types are for your choice. You can write here any type, that postgresql supports. But there may be problems with conversion to types, that rails can understand.

Comment: Also that link may help when working with time.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html

Comment: Happily, the latest SQLite seems to support 'timestamp with time zone' too

Comment: The caveat is important -- you can create a 'time with time zone' column in the database, but when you read it back, you'll get something like `unknown OID 1266: failed to recognize type of '<column_name>'. It will be treated as String`, and the values will be strings, e.g. `"17:15:00-07"`.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be confused about two separate things here - both common mistakes, almost everyone makes at least one of them.

Firstly "UTC format with timezone information" isn't specifying a time. It's specifying time AND place.

Secondly PostgreSQL's "timestamp with time zone" doesn't in fact store a time zone. It stores a UTC timestamp but it *accepts* a time zone. A better choice of name would be something like "absolute time". You can compare two of these values directly.

A timestamp without time zone doesn't actually give you a time unless you also have a place. You can't compare two of these unless you know which timezone each is in.

It sounds like what you want *is* a timestamp without time zone and a separate timezone. That way you can say "2pm on Tuesday, London Time".

Comment: Then either you've not understood what I've written, or the description of your problem is wrong.

Comment: I dont what the definition or the difference. I'm asked to store the whole thing,the time and the timezone. I need a migration to do this. Is there a way to use postgres time column with time zone option? If yes teach me how.

Comment: No, you can't. That's not what it does. I'm afraid I don't see how to explain the details more clearly to you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what your want, but this works for me:

```
add_column :table, :from_time, :timetz
add_column :table, :to_time, :timetz
```

But rails seems cannot to recognize timetz type, it will be treated as String. To work around this, i register timetz as time.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter.class_eval do
  def initialize_type_map_with_postgres_oids mapping
    initialize_type_map_without_postgres_oids mapping
    register_class_with_limit mapping, 'timetz',
                              ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::OID::Time
  end

  alias_method_chain :initialize_type_map, :postgres_oids
end
```

BTW, my environment is rails-4.2