# Storing a timestamp with a custom timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to store an "event time" that could be in any timezone. By default rails stores these in the DB as UTC and strips off our custom timezone. When we read the attribute back it is converted to our application's timezone - we lose the original timezone information.

We're working around this by storing the timestamp (as UTC) and an offset (an integer number of seconds) which is fine, but I'd really love to be able to store this as just one column and have rails use that rather than converting to UTC on write and to the application's timezone on read.

Is having rails store the timestamp in non-UTC just for this one field just not possible?

Comment: Depends a bit on the database, [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) supports timezones for both `timestamp` and `time` types. MySQL does not and relies on casting to UTC for storage and then back to system time.

Comment: Yep, postgres totally supports it. But ActiveRecord doesn't seem to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207856/railshow-to-create-a-time-column-with-timezone-on-postgres

Comment: Try declaring it as `t.column :event_time, 'timestamp with time zone'`.

Comment: The problem is that rails still converts it into UTC and saves with with a timezone of +0. The issue isn't the DB - it's rails converting the timestamp to UTC.

Comment: There is a more novel approach as well on that old question that involves declaring your own column type. I guess thats one way that it could be done but its not likely to be worth the effort.

Comment: Like I said - I'm not struggling with the column type - I'm trying to work out how to tell rails not to convert the timestamp to UTC when saving it.