# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: column "completed_at" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I initially created a Task model, including a `completed_at` field set as a `time` type, with the following migration:

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      ...
      t.time :completed_at
      ...

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

As the project evolved, I converted the `completed_at` field into a `timestamp` column, with the following migration:

```
class ChangeCompletedAtToBeTimestampInTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    change_column :tasks, :completed_at, :timestamp
  end
end
```

The app was working fine locally, with SQLite3, but when I tried to create a build for Heroku with PostgreSQL, with the `heroku run rails db:migrate --app my_app_name` command, I ran into the following error:

```
INFO -- : Migrating to ChangeCompletedAtToBeTimestampInTasks (20220713141025)
== 20220713141025 ChangeCompletedAtToBeTimestampInTasks: migrating ============
-- change_column(:tasks, :completed_at, :timestamp)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "completed_at" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING completed_at::timestamp without time zone".
```

Plus:

```
Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "completed_at" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING completed_at::timestamp without time zone".
```

And:

```
Caused by:
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "completed_at" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING completed_at::timestamp without time zone".
```

Inspired by [this 11-year-old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207856/railshow-to-create-a-time-column-with-timezone-on-postgres), I tried to modify the migration that changes the type of the `completed_at` column from time to timestamp by adding the `without time zone` option, but it did not solve the issue:

```
class ChangeCompletedAtToBeTimestampInTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    change_column :tasks, :completed_at, :timestamp without time zone
  end
end
```

Worth mentioning:

1. I am unsure whether fixing the problem actually requires to set the `timestamp` column as `with time zone` or `without time zone`.
2. I was not able to find documentation online showing how to apply the `without time zone` option in a Rails migration, so the code above may be incorrect.

Any thoughts on how to fix this and make the build pass?

Comment: Do you have any data that you want to preserve in the `completed_at` column at Heroku?

Comment: No: the app was only used in development so far. What I did to resolve this was to delete the `ChangeCompletedAtToBeTimestampInTasks` migration and update the `CreateTasks` so that `completed_at` is a `timestamp` from the start, and the I reset the database with seeds.

Comment: That's the easiest thing to do if you don't care about the data. Next you should install PostgreSQL in your development environment, developing with SQLite and deploying on PostgreSQL will cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: Agreed and done: PostgreSQL is now implemented in all three environments. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to pgadmin and try this query it is worked for me.

```sql
ALTER TABLE shop_orders ALTER COLUMN appointment_datetime TYPE TIMESTAMP USING appointment_datetime::TIMESTAMP;
```

Thanks